# python popen.stdout.readline() hangs

Tags: python, stdout, popen

I am having a problem... does anyone knows why this code hangs in the while loop. The loop doesn't seem to catch the last line of the `stdout`.

```
working_file = subprocess.Popen(["/pyRoot/iAmACrashyProgram"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

line = working_file.stdout.readline()
working_file.stdout.flush()
while working_file != "" :
    print(line)
    line = working_file.stdout.readline()
    working_file.stdout.flush()
```

The script hangs with the curser just blinking when `readline()` is encountered. I don't understand why. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Going on a guess here, but I've found that p.stdout.read*() will always be a blocking call, and if there isn't any data to return, then it keeps blocking. A nonblocking read may help you out.

Comment: at the risk of sounding like a massive idiot could you explain what you meen by nonblocking read, thanks :)

Comment: read() will hang if there's no data to read. It will only return once there is data (or enough of it) to return. A nonblock read causes it to return data immediately, and if there is none, then no data will be returned. Thus it doesn't hang (or, it's not a blocking call: _nonblocking call_).

Comment: Does the program want input on stdin?

Comment: im not so hot on program io and streams etc, anyone know where i could find a place to read up on the concepts, i still dont quite understand what flush() does and why

Answer (score 7):

Does doing a nonblocking read help you out?

```
import fcntl
import os

def nonBlockReadline(output):
    fd = output.fileno()
    fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    try:
        return output.readline()
    except:
        return ''

working_file = subprocess.Popen(["/pyRoot/iAmACrashyProgram"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

line = nonBlockReadline(working_file.stdout)
working_file.stdout.flush()
while working_file != "" :
    print(line)
    line = nonBlockReadline(working_file.stdout)
    working_file.stdout.flush()
```

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but will this work better? It just reads all the data, instead of reading only one line at a time. It's a little more readable to me.

```
import fcntl
import os

def nonBlockRead(output):
    fd = output.fileno()
    fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    try:
        return output.read()
    except:
        return ''

working_file = subprocess.Popen(["/pyRoot/iAmACrashyProgram"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

stdout = ''

while working_file.poll() is None:
    stdout += nonBlockRead(working_file.stdout)

# we can probably save some time and just print it instead...
#print(stdout)

stdout = stdout.splitlines()
for line in stdout:
    print(line)
```

Edit: A generalized script which should be more suited for your use case:

```
import fcntl
import os

def nonBlockRead(output):
    fd = output.fileno()
    fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    try:
        return output.read()
    except:
        return ''

working_file = subprocess.Popen(["/pyRoot/iAmACrashyProgram"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

while working_file.poll() is None:
    stdout = nonBlockRead(working_file.stdout)

    # make sure it returned data
    if stdout:
        # process data
        working_file.stdin.write(something)
```

Comment: You get an A for effort.  I hope this works.  (Thanks by the way, I learned quite a bit from this.)

Comment: wow, ill try it out, i cant say i fully understand it all though:) Im actually trying to write a python script that launches an external process and listens to it, then based on its output writes some values to its stdin. im a little out of my depth though, i feel like there must be a more elegant way than what im trying, you live and you learn :)

Comment: Based on your use case, it's possible that the blocking may have nothing to do with your issue, but hopefully this'll still help out. I added a script more suited for your problem, however it's still nonblocking (but that can easily be fixed with `working_file.stdout.readline()`).

Comment: Actually yes. Apparently fcntl is Unix only. The equivalent to fcntl is win32api, but apparently it's non trivial to port it... :/