# Creating temp GIT repo for testing is not working

Tags: python, git, gitlab

Hi guys my function (get_commit_sha) gets the commit sha from the latest commit. I now have to test this function.
For that I have to create different test szenarios and a couple temp git repositories only for testing which will be created in the test functions. In this repository I want to push "fake", "senseles" commits just for testing the function.

Comment: What about this: Copy the whole codebase to another folder, init a new git repo there, test your code, and if it seems to be working, just copy and paste the whole codebase back to the original repo and commit the changes. Be careful and do not copy the `.git` folder, just the code.

Comment: Or test it on your original repo, and if it works, squash all your "test" commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create temporary directory using `tempfile` standard library:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Change working directory to the new temp directory: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir

Then either use `os.system("git init && touch file && git add file && git commit -m Test")` or use git python library:

https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#tutorial-label

Cleanup by deleting the temp directory:

[Easiest way to rm -rf in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814167/easiest-way-to-rm-rf-in-python)

E.g.: Create test repo like this:

```py
import os
import tempfile

def test_repo():
    """Creates test repository with single commit and return its path."""
    temporary_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    os.chdir(temporary_dir)

    os.system("git init")
    os.system("touch file1")
    os.system("git add file1")
    os.system("git commit -m Test")

    return temporary_dir

print(test_repo())
```

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for your answer :) I have to give an input parameter (repo) to my function get_commit_sha(repo). What should I put in my case? I mean if I do it with your answer. That confused me a little.

Comment: I changed my test function, could you have a look?  @Roman cause I cant write testrepo as an input parameter

Comment: Do have any idea for good assertions in this test? What I already did is checking the length of the commit sha. I should do more tests, (false positive tests) @Roman

Comment: Well you can get the commit sha using git command line tools, using popen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16561182/12118546 Also you can create empty repo without commit and test what your tools what do then. Also you can test what will happen, when path is entirely invalid, zero length and also when it points to directory without git repo... You can test what it does when there is more commits in the repo etc...

Comment: Thanks I did first commit, more than one commit and empty repo :) Could you upvote my question if you think it was a helpful question?

Comment: Is there any way to do this in a loop? creatinf 10 files adding them and commiting? It does not word cause the command in os.system is a string @roman

Comment: for file in range(0, 10):
            test_file = "touch file " + str(file)
            os.system(test_file)
            os.system("git add .")
            os.system("git commit -m Test")