# Non-blocking read on subprocess PIPE in Python, one byte at a time

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe

I have implemented a variant on the code in this question:

*[A non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/a-non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python)*

To try and read the output in real time from this dummy program `test.py`:

```
import time, sys

print "Hello there"
for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(0.1)
    sys.stdout.write("\r%d"%i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
print
print "Go now or I shall taunt you once again!"
```

The variation on the other question is that the calling program must read character by character, not line by line, as the dummy program `test.py` outputs progress indication all on one line by use of `\r`.  So here it is:

```
import sys,time
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
from threading  import Thread

try:
    from Queue import Queue, Empty
except ImportError:
    from queue import Queue, Empty  # Python 3.x

ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names

def enqueue_output(out, queue):
    while True:
        buffersize = 1
        data = out.read(buffersize)
        if not data:
            break
        queue.put(data)
    out.close()

p = Popen(sys.executable + " test.py", stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, close_fds=ON_POSIX)
q = Queue()
t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
t.daemon = True # Thread dies with the program
t.start()

while True:
    p.poll()
    if p.returncode:
        break
    # Read line without blocking
    try:
        char = q.get_nowait()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    except Empty:
        pass
    else: # Got line
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()

print "left loop"
sys.exit(0)
```

Two problems with this

- It never exits - `p.returncode` never returns a value and the loop is not left. How can I fix it?
- It's really slow! Is there a way to make it more efficient without increasing `buffersize`?

Comment: According to the [docs for Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor), setting `bufsize=1` means "line buffered". You probably want 0 (unbuffered). Also, why do you need the time.sleep(0.1) after `char = q.get_nowait()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Markku K. pointed out, you should use `bufsize=0` to read one byte at a time.

Your code doesn't require a non-blocking read. You can simplify it:

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen([sys.executable, "test.py"], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=0)
for b in iter(partial(p.stdout.read, 1), b""):
    print b # it should print as soon as `sys.stdout.flush()` is called
            # in the test.py
p.stdout.close()
p.wait()
```

Note: reading 1 byte at a time is very inefficient.

Also, in general, there could be [a block-buffering issue](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect#Q:_Why_not_just_use_a_pipe_.28popen.28.29.29.3F) that sometimes can be solved using [`pexpect`, `pty` modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279) or [`unbuffer`, `stdbuf`, `script` command-line utilities](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/1321).

For Python processes you could use `-u` flag to force unbuffering (binary layer) of stdin, stdout, stderr streams.

Comment: Cool, that clarifies things.  Presumably if the above code is part of a GUI I do need non blocking reads or a separate thread to handle them?

Comment: @SideshowBob: yes. If you want to get subprocess' output in a GUI in a portable manner; then [a thread+queue make sense](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288) or something like [`io_add_watch()`](https://gist.github.com/zed/8a255e81eb87431c0e63) if you know how much you can read without blocking e.g., if subprocess' output is line-buffered then `.readline()` inside `io_add_watch()` callback should *not* block.

Comment: `io_add_watch`-based solution is rather brittle if the fds are blocking

Comment: Have an accept :) I ended up using my original code with the modifications you suggest here - `bufsize=0`, `p.stdout.close()` and `p.wait()`