# Handling tcpdump output in python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, tcpdump

Im trying to handle tcpdump output in python.

What I need is to run tcpdump (which captures the packets and gives me information) and read the output and process it.

The problem is that tcpdump keeps running forever and I need to read the packet info as soon as it outputs and continue doing it.

I tried looking into subprocess of python and tried calling tcpdump using popen and piping the stdout but it doesnt seem to work.

Any directions on how to proceed with this.

```
import subprocess

def redirect():
    tcpdump = subprocess.Popen("sudo tcpdump...", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    while True:
        s = tcpdump.stdout.readline()
        # do domething with s

redirect()
```

Comment: Can you post your code so far? Thanks.

Comment: you could [use pseudo-tty to force line-buffered output](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can make tcpdump line-buffered with "-l".  Then you can use subprocess to capture the output as it comes out.

```
import subprocess as sub

p = sub.Popen(('sudo', 'tcpdump', '-l'), stdout=sub.PIPE)
for row in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print row.rstrip()   # process here
```

Comment: use `for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''): print line,` in Python 2 due to ["readahead buffer" bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue3907)

Comment: `for line in p.stdout:` introduces unnecessary delay in the output on Python 2 (OP wants: *"as soon as it outputs"*). Use `iter(..)` as I've mentioned above. See [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)

Answer (score 3):

By default, pipes are block buffered and interactive output is line buffered.  It sounds like you need a line buffered pipe - coming from tcpdump in a subprocess.

In the old days, we'd recommend Dan Bernstein's "pty" program for this kind of thing.  Today, it appears that pty hasn't been updated in a long time, but there's a new program called "emtpy" which is more or less the same idea:
http://empty.sourceforge.net/

You might try running tcpdump under empty in your subprocess to make tcpdump line buffered even though it's writing to a pipe.

Comment: python has `pty` module in stdlib. Or `pexpect` could be used. There are also `stdbuf`, `script`, `unbuffer` utilities that may force line-buffered output