# Python Requests - How to calculate the total network consumption of a single request-response cycle

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am writing a script to scrape the data from web. I would like to calculate the Size of each request and response to monitor my network consumption. So, Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

One would be tempted in using the response header to have an idea of the network usage :

```
>>> response = requests.get('http://edition.cnn.com')
>>> response.headers['Content-Length']
'28321'
```

**Problem** :

This is not accurate, from a network consumption standpoint ! Indeed, the content-length header field gives us the size of the HTTP response body, without regard for HTTP headers, and the complete ethernet/IP/TCP headers.

After adding the size of all corresponding packets on wireshark, I end up with 30784 bytes, without including the TCP acks (8% variation in my case, which jumps to **13%** if I add the handshake, HTTP request and connection closure).

**Some insights** :

My advice would be to `tcpdump` HTTP traffic (which I define here by traffic to port 80, being aware that it is wrong), and to process the output with some good old python.

You can use `sudo tcpdump -n "dst port 80" -w cap.pcap` to dump all traffic to port 80, and then refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904231/handling-tcpdump-output-in-python) regarding how to process the output.

Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: I tried to follow your way but, there is no "Content-Length" on my request header.