# Can't get python subprocess stdin to work on linux

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin, popen

Let's say I have a directory call **h33/** in my current location and I want to delete it.  In shell I'd type `rm -ri h33` and it would be gone.  In python I wrote:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['rm','-ri','h33'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate('yes')
```

This works beautifully, if there aren't any files in the directory!  So if I run that same linux command, I have to answer yes to enter folder, yes to delete a single file i have in there, and then yes to delete the directory.  So I wrote:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['rm','-ri','h33'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for i in range(3):
    proc.communicate('yes')
```

... it doesn't work! not sure why though.

```
rm: descend into directory ‘hr33’? rm: remove regular empty file ‘hr33/blank’? rm: remove directory ‘hr33’? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiDel.py", line 6, in <module>
    proc.communicate("yes")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 806, in communicate
    return self._communicate(input)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1377, in _communicate
    self.stdin.flush()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

The main thing I want to do is be able to accommodate multiple inputs using subprocess (I hope that makes sense).  Please help me out

Comment: What's wrong with `shutil.rmtree()`?

Comment: Why are you using the `-i` switch at all then? Simply remove that option, add `-f` if you have to, and you *will not be asked*.

Comment: But most of all, why not use `shutil.rmtree()` instead? Python has the tools you need already!

Comment: And last but not least, you perhaps were looking for `pexpect` instead to handle 'interactive' communication with a subprocess.

Comment: I think  there is a misunderstanding.  The rm command was just an example. What I was really looking to do is handle interactive comm with python. I will look into pexpect tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Why not forcing the directory to be deleted without answering anything :

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['rm','-rf','h33'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.communicate()` closes the pipes and waits for the subprocesses to exit so you may call it at most once. Assuming `rm` is just an example of some interactive program that accepts input (otherwise, use `shutil.rmtree()` or `rm -rf` as suggested in the comments):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(['rm','-ri','h33'], stdin=PIPE)
proc.communicate(b'yes\n' * 3)
```

Or you could write to `proc.stdin` directly:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc = Popen(['rm','-ri','h33'], stdin=PIPE)
for i in range(3):
    proc.stdin.write(b'yes\n')
    proc.stdin.flush()
proc.communicate() # close pipes, wait for exit
```

In general you might need [`pty`, `pexpect` modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279) to interact with a subprocess:

```
import pexpect # $ pip install pexpect

pexpect.run("rm -ri h33", events={r"'\?": "yes\n"}, timeout=30)
```

It assumes that each prompt that requires the `yes` answer ends with `'?`.