# Python - getting values from 'interactive' (top, iftop, ntop etc) command line scenarios?

Tags: python, stdout, popen

Have been needing to write some code that recognises (and captures) when there's incoming/outgoing smb transfers on my server. I think  the  best way is to use popen with 'iftop'.

I was thinking I could just use popen to capture the data, but thing is iftop doesn't simply output the data - its an interactive environment that runs continuously until the user exits. So how can I parse values from these kind of programs into python?

Alternatively - a better option that popen(iftop) ?

Example:

```
foo.Popen("iftop" + someArguments)
//this is not stdout, so I can't pull string values (etc) from it :(
//how does?
```

Comment: what do you mean by `foo.Popen`? Isn't `Popen` a class in `subprocess`?

Comment: Likely this a duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419198/python-subprocess-readlines-hangs

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess, time
s = subprocess.Popen("iftop -s -t 1",shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
while not s.poll() == 0:
    time.sleep(1)
print(s.stdout.read())
```

Comment: This should be `iftop -s 1 -t` (the -s flag requires the parameter to come immediately after it). When there is no number following `-s`, iftop shows "unknown option -s".