# Piping popen curses-like input

Tags: python, windows, stdin, popen, curses

So typically my code would run like this:

```
child = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, shell=True, bufsize=0, universal_newlines = True)
```

The problem in my case is that I'm on Windows and the program I'm running doesn't use stdin, it uses some variation of a curses library it seems. Like it reads directly tty.

Is there a way to be able to pipe to this kind of input?

Comment: Probably not, if the lower-level is using the Windows console api.

Comment: a tty and Windows console are very different. If there were a tty; you could have tried [`pexpect` or `pty.openpty()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279)

Comment: Right, I'm just drawing the parallel not trying to make a literal statement.