# python subprocess with openssl

Tags: python, openssl, subprocess

I'm having a lot of trouble passing a string to the openssl commandline tool via python's subprocess like this:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    ["openssl", "rsa", "-in", pathFile, "-out", "id_rsa.out"],
    stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=False
)
try:
    process.communicate("some passphrase\n", timeout=2)
except:
    process.kill() #openssl stays alive otherwise.
```

The code above times out (with and without the std redirection in the Popen). I can use openssl normally through the terminal just fine, but I really need to be able to run this as part of my python script.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: read the first reason on: [Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe). Find command-line switch that woud allow to avoid passing the passphrase via tty, or [use `pexpect` or `pty.openpty()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279)

Comment: That's a good read. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The section PASS PHRASE ARGUMENTS on [the openssl man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/openssl.html) explains how the passphrase input mechanism works. To make your example work, you should tell openssl to take the passphrase from `stdin`. Using your example as a starting point, the following works for me:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(
    ["openssl", "rsa", "-in", pathFile, "-out", "id_rsa.out", "-passin", "stdin"],
    stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=False
)
process.communicate("passphrase\n")
```