# Trying to figure out pty

Tags: c, linux, pty

I have been trying to create a pseudo terminal to communicate with `mpg123`.  From all my readings I believe I have written the code properly, but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to connect the master side (PTY) with the external program.

I get the first available master with `posix_openpt`, and enable the slave with `grantpt` and `unlockpt`.  Then I get the PTS name with `ptsname` which can be used with `open` to get a file descriptor.  Next, I replace STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR of PTY with `dup2`.  Then I can use that file descriptor to communicate with the PTY.  But how does the master end connect to the external program that I wish to communicate with?

Here is my code so far:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fdm;
    int fds;
    pid_t pid;
    char *slave_name;
    char *program_name;

    program_name = basename(argv[0]);

    if(argc != 1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s\n", program_name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((fdm = posix_openpt(O_RDWR)) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: posix_openpt failed (%s)\n", program_name, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(grantpt(fdm) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: grantpt failed (%s)\n", program_name, strerror(errno));
        close(fdm);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(unlockpt(fdm) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: unlockpt failed (%s)\n", program_name, strerror(errno));
        close(fdm);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((slave_name = ptsname(fdm)) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: ptsname failed\n", program_name);
        close(fdm);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((pid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: fork failed (%s)\n", program_name, strerror(errno));
        close(fdm);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(pid == 0)    // Child
    {
        if(setsid() == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: setsid failed (%s)\n", program_name, strerror(errno));
            close(fdm);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if((fds = open(slave_name, O_RDWR)) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: open failed (%s)\n", program_name, strerror(errno));
            close(fdm);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        close(fdm);

        if(dup2(fds, STDIN_FILENO) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: dup2(1) failed (%s)\n", program_name, strerror(errno));
            close(fds);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(dup2(fds, STDOUT_FILENO) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: dup2(2) failed (%s)\n", program_name, strerror(errno));
            close(fds);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(dup2(fds, STDERR_FILENO) == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: dup2(3) failed (%s)\n", program_name, strerror(errno));
            close(fds);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        close(fds);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else        // Parent
    {
        wait(&pid);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I'm not looking for a hand out, just an explaination.  How do I connect to mpg123?  Where do I connect to mpg123, in the child or the parent?

Comment: I remember having played much with PTY long ago. If I remember well, I wrote several codes by hacing the source code of the standard `script` program. It is a short code, very easy to hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would call execvp in the child to execute mpg123. You then communicate through the master file descriptor (`fdm`) which acts as the user of the terminal (TTYs are meant for human users).

Are you certain you need to use a pty for this? Most programs work fine with just normal pipes for stdin/stdout. Those you can create by calling `pipe` or `sockerpair` in the parent process. Even better, if you only need to read or only to write you can use `popen` which simplifies the interface a lot.

Comment: I did try popen. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678441/why-wont-popen-communicate-with-mpg123

Comment: Alright, I'm still wondering if there isn't a better interface than to simulate a human user, but that's not really my call.

Comment: Your first paragraph was what I needed to complete my task.  Ty.

Comment: There are a couple of other ways to communicate with `mpg123`.  You can use the -R to create a fifo to send commands through, or you can try and use libmpg123.  The reason I chose the simulate human input is with the other two methods you must constantly read the output to find the end of a track.  With human input, I can play an enitre playlist and use the forward and backward keys without ever needing to know the current state of `mpg123`.