# Python reading output from subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a program which opens a subprocess and communicates with it by writing to its `stdin` and reading from its `stdout`.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['foo'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

proc.stdin.write('stuff\n')
proc.stdin.flush()
```

The problem is that when reading, it always blocks if I call `proc.stdout.read()`, and when I try to read line by line using the following:

```
output = str()
while proc.stdout in select.select([proc.stdout], [], [])[0]:
    output += proc.stdout.readline()
```

it still blocks because `select.select` returns `proc.stdout` even after all the output has been read already. What can I do?

note that I am not using `proc.communicate` because I would like to communicate with the process multiple times

Comment: What kind of output are you expected to read from `stdout`? A fixed number of lines? A fixed number of bytes? Multiple lines until an empty line is found? Other? In other words: when should is program supposed to stop reading from stdout and start doing something else?

Comment: ... or maybe do you want to read only what's available right now? (With the intent of implementing what is known as "asynchronous communication")

Comment: How much data is the subprocess producing to stdout? There's a [warning about PIPEs filling up](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stderr) and blocking subprocesses.

Comment: it is not a fixed number of lines; i write a command to the process and it returns some number of lines, which varies.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12419198/python-subprocess-readlines-hangs seems pretty similar