# Realtime output from a shell command in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm telling jupyter to execute a python script:

```
!python build_database.py
```

When executed from the terminal, the python script prints the progress during execution. However, in the jupyter notebook, I get all output printed as a list of strings, AFTER the execution.
Is there a way to see the output live?

Comment: More full featured support in Jupyter is to use `%run` and not `!python`. In this example, that would be`%run build_database.py`. It often gives a different, better experience depending on your system. Plus, it has more options, see [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run).

Comment: There's some settings about buffering that can be adjusted. There's a related discussion on the Jupyter Discourse Community Forum [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-show-the-result-of-shell-instantly/8947?u=fomightez).

Answer (score 13):

It looks like it is not possible out of the box. The output handling of shell commands is buried deep in ipython internals.

One of solutions i would recommend is to create custom magic method based on code below.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/9820085)

Based on it i created a simple magic method that you can use:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic


@register_line_magic
def runrealcmd(command):
    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1, close_fds=True)
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
        print(line.rstrip().decode('utf-8'))
    process.stdout.close()
    process.wait()
```

Or `Popen` can be used as context manager. So the code will be a bit more readable and reliable. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

> Popen objects are supported as context managers via the with statement: on exit, standard file descriptors are closed, and the process is waited for.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic


@register_line_magic
def runrealcmd(command):
    with Popen(
        command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1, close_fds=True
    ) as process:
        for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b""):
            print(line.rstrip().decode("utf-8"))
```

**Usage:**

```
%runrealcmd ping -c10 www.google.com
```

Above code probably could be written better but for your needs it should be perfectly fine.

Comment: It doesn´t change the fact for me that the result is returned after complete execution.

Comment: I will research the problem some more and get back to you.

Comment: Maybe an important detail: The script build_database.py uses print() to output the progress I want to see in realtime

Comment: I have updated my answer, take a look if that solution satisfies you

Comment: I get: `ValueError: close_fds is not supported on Windows platforms if you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr` and with `close_fds=False` it is not realtime

Comment: so you removed `close_fds` and it is not printing in realtime?

Comment: I set `close_fds=False` and it is not printing in realtime

Comment: You can try code above with -u param on python: %runrealcmd python -u build_database.py. Moreover you should put Kamil Niski's runrealcmd code to .ipython\profile_default\startup\runcmd.py so it automatically load custom magic

Comment: I've got similar issue which alas the above approach does not resolve. In my case wanting progress reporting from the mpi example on https://emcee.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/parallel/ . The code runs alright but I don't see any output until the subprocess is complete.

Comment: Thanks @KamilNiski for the post! This fixed a very bizarre issue with the `matplotlib_iterm2` package inside `jupyter console`: https://github.com/oselivanov/matplotlib_iterm2/pull/4

Comment: @LukeDavis great to hear that! You should also be able to use `Popen` as context manager. I've added example in my original answer.

Answer (score 3):

I refer to this answer: [How to show real time process command line in Jupyter Notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71635554/how-to-show-real-time-process-command-line-in-jupyter-notebook)

Just execute your python script as:

```
%run build_database.py
```