# Cannot import specific function in Jupyter notebook, however, some function in the same "~.py" can be imported

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-import, custom-function

I have `utils.py` and there are two functions: `runrealcmd`, `mol_with_atom_index`

If I try to import the two function with the following code:

```
from utils import mol_with_atom_index, runrealcmd
```

It fails to import runrealcmd. The error message is like below:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'runrealcmd' from 'utils'
```

However, if I try to import only the `mol_with_atom_index` with the following code:

```
from utils import mol_with_atom_index
```

It successes. The function of `mol_with_atom_index` can be imported in Jupyter notebook.

However, the function of `runrealcmd` cannot be imported in Jupyter notebook although both of the two functions are in the same `utils.py` file.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'runrealcmd' from 'utils'
```

### utils.py

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from IPython.core.magic import register_line_magic

@register_line_magic
def runrealcmd(command):
    # Display instantly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545512/realtime-output-from-a-shell-command-in-jupyter-notebook
    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1, close_fds=True)
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
        print(line.rstrip().decode('utf-8'))
    process.stdout.close()
    process.wait()


def mol_with_atom_index(mol):
    for atom in mol.GetAtoms():
        atom.SetAtomMapNum(atom.GetIdx())
    return mol
```

Comment: Something is weird because the code you posted combined with `from utils import mol_with_atom_index, runrealcmd` works fine. Are you clearing your kernel first after changing your `utils.py` code?  You can launch a session via mybinder by [clicking here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/pythonista_skewedf/HEAD) and try it out on a separate, **temporary** system in your browser.

Comment: Thank you. It's so weird. Actually, there were 4 functions in utils.py, but only one function (mol_with_atom_index) was imported... I think that I need to ty to clear my kernel first.

Comment: Once you use `import <package>`, the kernel will import and record it has already imported that package. If you then put `import <package>` for the same package again in another cell it will 'run' that code; however, behind the scenes it won't have imported again because it noted it already did. Besides restarting the kernel, you can [reload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5399339/8508004) modules.

Comment: Not Clearing the kernel before importing the same-named function from the other path seems the cause. After clearing the kernel, it has been solved. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

(Jupyter notebook) If you want to import the same-named function (previously imported with the same name) from the other path, you should restart the kernel first.