# How to show real time process command line in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ipython

Example, I have this code saved as `test.py`

```
import time
for i in range(0, 10):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(3.0)
```

When I try to run this on ipynb with `!python test.py`
It processed but it doesn't show realtime in output.
I want it to be like show 0, then pause 3 seconds and then show 1 .... etc. in output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try using `%run test.py` or `%run test.py -i` in a cell in your notebook.

(See [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run).)

`!` sends what you put after it off to a separate temporary shell instance. That instance runs what you sent as process entirely and then upon completion (depending on system) brings the output back to the notebook & closes itself up and cleans up everything.

Actually how it handles things like this can differ on different systems. For example in sessions launched from [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements#python-environment-with-a-requirementstxt) by clicking `launch binder` (select 'Help' > 'Launch Classic Notebook' if you prefer the other interface although the interface choice makes no difference as both behaved same with your code there), I see `!python test.py` works as you seek.
However, in general it is best not run scripts in notebooks that way as **the [magic `%run` command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) is best used for running scripts inside a notebook** as it is more full-featured and uses the environment in which your notebook is served. So on top of maybe not returning output until the end, `!python` won't necessarily use the same environment.

Comment: Sorry to ask you again, does magic command have to be run in my local environment?

Comment: You run it in a cell in the notebook for running a script in a notebook. (I edited answer to add that.) That way it will use the environment the presumably is what your notebook sees. The `!` approach doesn't mean necessarily it does. This parallels why there is now `%pip install` & `%conda install` for running inside notebook cells, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). Those insure packages install to the correct environment; anything that uses the exclamation point in front of `pip` or `conda` is outdated.